# Developer access and when a token is valid

Tags: api, architecture, permissions

I apologise if the title is a little confusing, but I was a little stuck with the wording.

I'm currently working on a section of an application to allow users to grant developers access to their data through the application. This comes in a little 'Allow Some great app to access your account with the following permissions'. The application developer adds the required permissions, then when the user goes to authorize the application, these permissions are are displayed. If the user is happy to grant these permissions, the user shall press 'Grant'. This means that the user has agreed to every permission that has been displayed, and therefore this generates an API access token for the relevant application.

The issue now is that it has came to the attention that people may want to remove these permissions at a further date. At the moment, if the user would like to remove permissions, all permissions will be removed or disabled. The reasoning behind this is that if a single permission is removed from the application, the token that they authorized with is technically invalid as it does not have the permissions that were given to it when first creating the token.

Whilst this seems logical, there are also circumstances where the user would want to deny access for the third party application for a single feature (eg. The external application had a bug that was creating bad behaviour in a certain area, but was working fine in another area).

Would anybody be able to throw their two-cents in to this, as I'm having a hard time understanding if its best to allow modifications to a single permission in the event of problems, or to simply have to disable the application.

Comment: But why must the token become invalid when the permissions changes?

Comment: This was a view that I have concluded myself. The token is generated on the assumption that the user agrees to all the permissions requested by the application. If the user then revokes one of the permissions, surely this makes the token invalid? It's like agreeing to a terms of service, then halfway through using the service you decide you don't like the terms. You should then be terminated from the service, right, since you no longer agree with the terms?

Comment: If that's the scenario I agree. I thought the 3d party devs could cherry pick among a bunch of permissions, and that the app-owner in a later step could revoke permissions. eg. The 3d party dev requires permission to user data and location coordinates. The owner then revokes the permission to get access to the location of the users. Then the 3d party app still could get access to user data.

Comment: @Vic Actually, these permissions are built in to the application itself, so the user could revoke these permissions anyway. The point that I feel is that if a developer requests for permissions to access your account, a token should only ever be valid when the user agrees to the entirety of the permission set, in the same way that you have to agree to ALL the terms of service when using a service as opposed to being able to pick what you want and what you dont want. The ability is still there to revoke any permission at a later date, should that be needed.